# Google Maps Encode Polyline Rendering Wrong

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having problems rendering polylines on a Google map for my univer. The result should look like the polyline on: http://goo.gl/U18jBJ (Google maps directions from Leeds to London).

I am rendering individual paths from each step from the Google directions API instead of just getting a Google directions map, so that I can use a loop to render the individual paths from each step from the Google directions API and the polyline paths in the Rome2Rio Search API result.

The following php writes out the javascript for the map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.796490000000006, -1.5473400000000002);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("routeMap"), myOptions);

<?php $stopCounter = 0;
foreach($travelData[0]->stops as $stop):
    echo 'var stopLatlng'.$stopCounter.' = new google.maps.LatLng('.$stop->location.');';
    echo 'var marker'.$stopCounter.' = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: stopLatlng'.$stopCounter.',
              map: map,
              title: \''.$stop->name.'\'
          });';
    ++$stopCounter;
endforeach; 
$segementCounter = 0;
foreach($travelData[0]->segments as $segment):
    echo 'var routePath'.$segementCounter.' = \''.$segment->path.'\'; ';
    echo 'var path'.$segementCounter.' = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(String(routePath'.$segementCounter.')); ';
    echo 'var route'.$segementCounter.' = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: path'.$segementCounter.',
              strokeColor: "#FF0000",
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight: 2
            }); ';
    ++$segementCounter;
endforeach;
$segementCounter = 0;
foreach($travelData[0]->segments as $segment):
    echo 'route'.$segementCounter.'.setMap(map);';
    ++$segementCounter;
endforeach;?>

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="routeMap" class="floatLeft">
</div>
```

From my research, it seems that it is the javascript which is causing problems (possibly by escaping characters) but I cannot find a resolution. The code output by the php is here: http://jsfiddle.net/phily245/ebbCX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes in the encoded `path`  must be escaped with another backslash:

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/ebbCX/2/

using `json_encode` should preserve the original string(assuming that the backslashes have been escaped in the original string):

```
echo 'var routePath'.$segementCounter.' = '.json_encode($segment->path).';';
```

Comment: I was so close! Thank you :)

Comment: try using json_encode to transport the string(see above)